# CodeIgniter Upload from User Class

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

my problem is that i have a User Class with a edit_profile() function and i want the User to be able to upload their photo when editing their profile. when the form is submitted, it stays on the edit profile page using that edit_profile() function and updates their information but i can't get it to use the do_upload() function because that function has to be inside of the Upload Class. how can i do_upload() inside of the User Class/edit_profile() function?

hopefully that wasn't confusing. all help is appreciated!!!

thanks!

Comment: No it wasn't at all confusing without you posting any of your code... =o\ Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to know what you mean without seeing any code but its sounds like you are not loading the upload library.  You should be able to use any of the upload function after you have loaded it

```
$this->load->library('upload');
```

Comment: it must have been a long night because i accidentally had the library commented out... lol... guess i needed someone to point it out! thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understand what you mean, maybe this tutorial can help solve your problem :

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax/